# Using continuity + commutativity to define "limit"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $S$ be the set of real sequences, and $S_0\subset  S$ be the set of convergent real sequences. For each $f:\mathbf R\to\mathbf R$, we define $\bar{f}:S\to S$ by $$\bar{f}(\{x_n\})=\{f(x_n)\}.$$
It is known that

> if $f$ is continuous, then for each $\{x_n\}\in S_0$, $\{\lim f(x_n)\}\in S_0$ and $\bar{f}(\lim x_n)=\lim f(x_n).$ ----(#)

So in some sense, $f$ and $\lim$ commute for continuous $f$.

My question is, can we reverse the process, starting with the definition of continuous functions and use this commutativity to define the notion of the limit of a sequence? In other words, is there a *largest* set $S_0\subset S$ (i.e. contains all other possible $S_0$) and a unique function $\lim:S_0\to\mathbf R$ such that (#) holds?

Comment: $S_0=${constant sequences} works also...

Comment: @abx: good catch, seems that we need to add some restriction then

Comment: $S_0 = S$ and the projection onto the first term of the sequence work. Obviously it is not then unique, but it never is (for any $S_0$ and $i$, projection onto the $i$th term gives a function that commutes, by your definition of $\overline{f}$)

Comment: What can be added is the independence of the limit (and of the set $S$ of admissible sequences) of any finite number of elements in the sequence. Will you accept such addition?

Comment: @ fdeja, yes, that is reasonable.